# Can not see the resize handle of a react-grid-layout project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts, react-grid-layout

I have the following code:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem'
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import ResponsiveGridLayout from 'react-grid-layout'
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import {LineChart, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Line, BarChart, Tooltip, Legend, Bar} from 'recharts'



export default function Dashboard() {
  const layout = [
    { i: 'Data_1', x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1, minW: 1, maxW: 2, minH: 1, maxH: 2, isResizable: true, resizeHandles: ['se']},
    { i: 'Data_2', x: 1, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1, minW: 1, maxW: 2, minH: 1, maxH: 2, isResizable: true, resizeHandles: ['se']},
    { i: 'Add_butt', x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1, isDraggable: false },
  ];
<ResponsiveGridLayout
        className="layout"
        layout={layout}
        cols={4}
        rowHeight={300}
        width={2000}
        compactType='vertical'
      > 
...
</ResponsiveGridLayout>
```

Unfortunately I cannot see the handle in at the datas. Also could be helpful that I use them in the following manner:

```js
<div key="Data_1">
  <Card variant='outlined'>
    <LineChart width={500} height={300} data={data} margin={{right: 50, top: 20}}>
      <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
      <YAxis/>
      <CartesianGrid stroke="#eee" strokeDasharray="5 5"/>
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#8884d8" />
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
    </LineChart>
  </Card>
</div>
```

I am really not sure on why the resizehandle is not showing, at first I thought it had to do with the `Card` but it unfortunately didn't work after I deleted the `Card`s. I am not sure If I define something wrong, or it has to do with some uncompatibility the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your component and it will show your the dra

import 'react-grid-layout/css/styles.css'